# How to render a component without using a Route element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is my React component:

```
const Auth = () => {  

useEffect(() => { 
document.body.classList.add("bg-default");  
return () => {  
document.body.classList.remove("bg-default");      
}    
}, [])    

const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();  

if (isAuthenticated){  
return <AdminLayout><Dashboard/></AdminLayout>      
}  return (
```

But It's a problem I can't understand. `AdminLayout` works in every component but when I return it in the way above I get: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined*

The error is in this:

```
<AdminNavbar {...this.props} 
brandText{this.getBrandText(this.props.location.pathname)} />
```

I think it's about react-router but I don't how to fix it, I'm not very confident with react-router.

I fixed in this way:

```
const Auth = () => {  

useEffect(() => { 
document.body.classList.add("bg-default");  
return () => {  
document.body.classList.remove("bg-default");      
}    
}, [])    

const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();  

if (isAuthenticated){  
return <AdminLayout><Dashboard/></AdminLayout>      
}  return (
```

But It's a problem I can't understand. AdminLayout works in every component but when I return it in the way above I get: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined*

The error is in this:

```
<AdminNavbar {...this.props} 
brandText{this.getBrandText(this.props.location.pathname)} />
```

Comment: First issue: You can't use hooks in a class-based component. Second issue: At the root level, a class component can only contain the things listed in the title. In a class-based component, the render method is equivalent (this is a massive oversimplification) to the body of a function component.

But, let's pretend that we could use hooks in class-based components, then the fix would be to simply move the code inside the render method.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that `AdminLayout` expects a prop called location, itself having a prop called pathname. I suppose you could either render it as `<AdminLayout location={window.location} />`, or change `this.props.location.pathname` to `window.location.pathname`, this assuming that you're trying to render different texts depending on where the user is.